# группировка множества строк в 1 c помощью Python

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите как сгруппировать множество строк в 1 с помощью Python
У меня есть DF (образец) на самом деле колонок около ~ 100

```
info = [['ID 75000', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns=['user_id', 'oper1', 'oper2', 'oper3', 'oper4', 'oper5', 'oper6', 'oper7', 'oper8', 'oper9', 'oper10'])

Необходимо сгруппировать чтобы получилось 
user_id   oper1 oper2   oper3   oper4   oper5   oper6   oper7   oper8   oper9   oper10
0 ID 75000    1     1       1       1       1       0       0       0       0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Попрообуйте так наверное

```py
import pandas as pd

info = [['ID 75000', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ['ID 75000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns=['user_id', 'oper1', 'oper2', 'oper3', 'oper4', 'oper5', 'oper6', 'oper7', 'oper8', 'oper9', 'oper10'])

grouped = df.groupby('user_id').sum().reset_index()

print(grouped)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.